# OSX 10.6 integration into NIS/netgroup/automount infrastructure

Tags: email, nis, osx-snow-leopard, automount

I have an existing infrastructure where accounts are maintained under NIS (yp) with no local unix accounts.  Also, all the standard maps including hosts, mail aliases, netgroups, etc...are maintained in this form.  Extensive use of the UNIX/Linux automounter with items scattered over the network on NFS servers.  There are NO ACLs on any local or shared files.  All mail needs to use basically the nullclient sendmail configuration feeding into a different system.

I now have a requirement to integrate an Apple OSX 10.6 system into this environment and make it run seamlessly.

My initial reading and second-hand information seems to indicate that this may not be possible on the native OSX 10.6 system.  I'm concerned.

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this task and make everybody happy?

Thanks

PS: I have never used an Apple OSX system.

Comment: Apparently there is the Sun automounter that is available in this operating system.  Thus I'm closing this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't had any luck getting the auto-mounter stuff, but then again I didn't really try that hard.

I was successful in getting my 10.6 macs (and earlier) to accept NIS authentication however.

In a nutshell, it's a matter of ensuring the passwords are stored in a format OSX understands (MD5 or DES), and knowing that the directory utility is under /System/Library/CoreServices in 10.6, instead of /Applications/Utilities like it was in earlier releases of OSX.

The NFS mounts are handled by DiskUtility (File->NFS Mounts) in 10.6, just be sure to include resvport and vers=3 (or 2) under the advanced section.  OSX does not have real support for NFS4, so don't even try.

What little I know I've tossed on my blog, petuu.org