# What NIS maps are needed for OSX 10.6 to authenticate?

Tags: mac-osx, nis

What NIS maps are necessary for OSX 10.6 to authenticate?

I have an ubuntu-sever sharing NIS, and from the OSX client, ypcat passwd, ypcat group and (as root) ypcat shadow.byname all work, and return the correct info.

If I type groups kyle (a user in NIS, but not on the local machine), I get all the correct group information.

The only thing that doesn't work, is logging in.

(And yes, if I point an ubuntu box to that NIS server, everything authenticates off of it just fine).

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X 10.6 cannot use NIS for authentication (as far as I know). With 10.5 it worked well with our Debian server, but after the upgrade logging in stopped working :-(

But I found the following posts, they can probaly help you:

- https://superuser.com/questions/163807
- [OSX 10.6 integration into NIS/netgroup/automount infrastructure](https://serverfault.com/questions/186698/osx-10-6-integration-into-nis-netgroup-automount-infrastructure)

Comment: Actually it will.  I should have taken this question down, as I figured it out.  It wasn't an issue of missing maps, it was an issue of the wrong password-encryption type.  I have my notes on http://petuu.org

Comment: @Kyle__ Please post your solution on ServerFault and accept your own answer.  Otherwise, this unanswered question will be revived periodically, wasting everyone's time.